# EF6 Convert IQueryable to DbQuery

Tags: entity-framework, iqueryable

In Entity framework 6, when running the overload of the Include method that uses lambda expression to the context:

`Context.SomeEntity.Include(x => x.MyOtherEntity)`)

it returns an IQueryable, whereas when we use the one that uses string:

`Context.SomeEntity.Include("MyOtherEntity")`

it returns a DbQuery.

I need to return a DbQuery and don't want to use the string overload so that I can get inclusion errors at compile time.

How can I return a DbQuery after using the include with the lambda?

Comment: Why do you need DbQuery? Why do you not use the other overload then. You could use a custom method to pass in your Expression (x => x.MyOtherEntity) and build the string for it up manually. There are lots of those to find on SO

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't convert an `IQueryable` to a `DbQuery`. However, you can use this code to pass in an expression and get the required string.

Be sure to write some unit tests for this and adapt the method for your needs. I have not tested it properly yet.

```
public static string GetMemberName<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExp;
        if (!TryFindMemberExpression(expression.Body, out memberExp))
            return string.Empty;

        var memberNames = new Stack<string>();
        do
        {
            memberNames.Push(memberExp.Member.Name);
        }
        while (TryFindMemberExpression(memberExp.Expression, out memberExp));

        return string.Join(".", memberNames.ToArray());
    }


private static bool TryFindMemberExpression(Expression exp, out MemberExpression memberExp)
    {
        memberExp = exp as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (IsConversion(exp) && exp is UnaryExpression)
        {
            memberExp = ((UnaryExpression)exp).Operand as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExp != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsConversion(Expression exp)
    {
        return (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked);
    }
```